# how to use aop in common-pool

Tags: java, spring-aop, pool

I'm new to apache common pool.I use `pool.borrowObject();` to get a instance from pool and do `pool.returnObject(obj);` in the finally block.So I want to use aop instand of writing a finally block to return instane back to pool.I think spring aop can do this,but how to get the instance **"obj"** in the **aop:after**

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

    private GenericObjectPool<Foo> pool;

    @Override
    public void insert() {
        try {
            Foo obj = pool.borrowObject();
            //do something
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            pool.returnObject(obj);
        }
    }

    public GenericObjectPool getPool() {
        return pool;
    }

    public void setPool(GenericObjectPool pool) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if you need access to object inside aspect

if ServiceImpl has *prototype  scope*, you can do this

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

private Foo obj;

@Override
public void insert() {
    . .....
        obj = pool.borrowObject();
    . .....
    return obj;
}

public Foo getFooObj(){
   return obj;
}
```

}

If ServiceImpl has *singleton scope* , you can do this

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
private ThreadLocal serviceThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal();

@Override
public void insert() {
    . .....
        obj = pool.borrowObject();
        serviceThreadLocal.set(obj);
    . .....
    return obj;
}

public Foo getFooObj(){
   return serviceThreadLocal .get();
}
}
```

here you have access to the object from poll.

---

or you setup / wrap handling poll logic inside an aspect

add a custom annotation :

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApplyObjectFromPool {
}
```

and change a bit implementation :

```
@Component
public class ServiceImpl implements Service , HasObjectFromPool<Foo> {

    private Foo obj;

    @Override
    @ApplyObjectFromPool
    public void insert() {
        try {
            obj = getObjectFromPool();
            //do something
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Foo getObjectFromPool(){
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void setObjectFromPool(Foo object) {
        this.obj=object;
    }
}
```

and configure pointcut :

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ObjectFromPoolAspect {
    private GenericObjectPool pool = new GenericObjectPool();

    @Around("within(org........HasObjectFromPool+) && @annotation(applyObjectFromPool))")
    public Object applyObjectFromPool(ProceedingJoinPoint point ,
                  ApplyObjectFromPool applyObjectFromPool) throws Throwable {
        Object result;
        HasObjectFromPool target = (HasObjectFromPool) point.getTarget();
        Object objectFromPool = pool.borrowObject();
        try {
            target.setObjectFromPool(objectFromPool);
            result = point.proceed();
        }finally {
            pool.returnObject(objectFromPool);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

IMHO: if you use the pool only ServiceImpl leave it as is, if you have same logic in couple different places this about small refactoring and use [Template Method Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-template-method) or [Command Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command). In your case use aop it's the bad approach. You should change your code for making it available for aspect and not for improvement.